# Improve the speed of a Tomcat Server with MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat

I´m developing an application with 3 sides, desktop(JavaFX), server(Tomcat) and Android.

And a mySQLWorkbrench Database Server.

The app receive mails and convert them into tasks. The tasks are send to the android devices from the desktop app. The user of the Android device do the stuff with the task and send the task with new information to the server.

The desktop app takes the data from the database.

Now it´s working, but goes too slow from the desktop side, due to the server has a big payload¿?.

The server has 3 tasks:

- JavaMail email reader, and write in the database.
- Send PUSH messages to the Android devices and receive some information of them, and write in the database.
- Receive the GPS position from the Android devices, and write in the database.

My doubts are:

A)Separate the server side in 3 projects.

1. Mail reader
2. Send PUSH to the Android devices.
3. GPS position receptor.

B)Separate the database in 2 databases:

1. For the GPS position.
2. For the info of the tasks.

This steps will make the app faster?

Comment: Probably this question is better fit for http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Posted there too: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/264743/improve-the-speed-of-a-tomcat-server-with-mysql

Must I delete this question?